# Blazor Serverside does not trigger Install PWA dialogue on mobile?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Trying to auto trigger or at least trigger with a in-application UI element ( a button ) the installation dialogue. Yet, due some reason it doesn't triggers at all, and there is nothing specific in the Chrome's console.

the **manifest.json:**

```
{
   "name": "IRIS Application",
   "short_name": "IRIS ",
   "description": "Shows the state of IRIS panels",
   "start_url": "/",
   "scope": "/",
   "display": "standalone",
   "background_color": "#ffffff",
   "theme_color": "#03173d",
   "prefer_related_applications": false,
   "icons": [
      {
         "src": "icon-48.png",
         "sizes": "48x48",
         "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
         "src": "icon-72.png",
         "sizes": "72x72",
         "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
         "src": "icon-96.png",
         "sizes": "96x96",
         "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
         "src": "icon-144.png",
         "sizes": "144x144",
         "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
         "src": "icon-192.png",
         "type": "image/png",
         "sizes": "192x192"
      },
      {
         "src": "icon-512.png",
         "type": "image/png",
         "sizes": "512x512"
      }
   ]
}
```

**ServiceWorkerRegister.js:**

```
const serviceWorkerFileName = '/ServiceWorker.js';
const swInstalledEvent = 'installed';
const staticCachePrefix = 'blazor-cache-v';
const updateAlertMessage = 'Update available. Reload the page when convenient.';
const blazorAssembly = 'Teletek';
const blazorInstallMethod = 'PWAInstallable';
window.updateAvailable = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerFileName)
            .then(function (registration) {
                console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope);
                registration.onupdatefound = () => {
                    const installingWorker = registration.installing;
                    installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
                        switch (installingWorker.state) {
                            case swInstalledEvent:
                                if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                                    resolve(true);
                                } else {
                                    resolve(false);
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                        }
                    };
                };
            })
            .catch(error =>
                console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', error));
    }
});
window[ 'updateAvailable' ]
    .then(isAvailable => {
        if (isAvailable) {
            alert(updateAlertMessage);
        }
    });


function showAddToHomeScreen() {
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync(blazorAssembly, blazorInstallMethod)
        .then(function () { }, function (er) { setTimeout(showAddToHomeScreen, 1000); });
}

window.triggerInstall = function ()
{
    showAddToHomeScreen();
};

window.BlazorPWA = {
    installPWA: function () {
        if (window.PWADeferredPrompt) {
            window.PWADeferredPrompt.prompt();
            window.PWADeferredPrompt.userChoice
                .then(function (choiceResult) {
                    window.PWADeferredPrompt = null;
                });
        }
    }
};
```

**ServiceWorker.js:**

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', () => { });
```

**_Layout.cshtml**:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace TeletekServer.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link href="manifest.json" rel="manifest" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="512x512" href="icon-512.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="192x192" href="icon-192.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="IRIS.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>

    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="ServiceWorkerRegister.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.razor**:

```
@page "/"

@using MudBlazor

@inject IJSRuntime jSRuntime

<PageTitle>IRIS Server</PageTitle>
<div id="imgDiv">

    <img src="/logo.png" width="70%" height="15%" />
    <br />
    
</div>
<br />
<div id="btnDiv">
    <MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Button" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" Class="ml-auto" OnClick="onBtnInstallClick">Install</MudButton>
</div>
@code
{
    public async void onBtnInstallClick( MouseEventArgs e )
    {
        
        await jSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync( "BlazorPWA.installPWA" );
    }
}

<style>
    #imgDiv {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    #btnDiv {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
</style>
```

- Why the "Install PWA" dialogue does not appears ?
- It is possible to auto appear such a dialogue if the application is not installed ?, and "how?" if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your call from Blazor to JS calls `BlazorPWA.installPWA` which should then use the stored `PWADeferredPrompt` to ask the user to install...

However, you never store anything as `PWADeferredPrompt`.

`PWADeferredPrompt` in this case should be the event instance passed to the handler for the `beforeinstallprompt` event of the window.

You are missing this code - or a variant of it:

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function (e) {
    // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
    e.preventDefault();
    // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
    window.PWADeferredPrompt = e;

    showAddToHomeScreen();

});
```

Comment: Still can't make it show the installation prompt.
Already given up on the try to show custom prompt. I wanna now even to show the default prompt. :|